# Almost sure convergence problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be independent random variables: $X_n=n^2-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $X_n=-1$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$. Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k$. How to prove that $\frac{S_n}{n}\rightarrow -1$ almost surely? Why is this sequence of random variables able to avoid laws of large numbers and CLT?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: First, I think you meant $S_n/n \to 0$. Second, CLT has nothing to do with this, unless you normalize by $\sqrt{n}$, instead of $n$. Third, you cannot directly apply strong law of large numbers to this because it assumes that $X_1, X_2,\dots$ are identically distributed.

Comment: No, $S_n/n \to -1$ is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sum_n 1/n^2$ converges so almost surely all but finitely many $X_n$ are $-1$.  In fact you don't even need to assume $X_n$ are independent.